# "Hostname fcm.googleapis.com not verified"error occurred suddenly from FCM request

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

When my Java-based server tries to send in-app push message to my App by calling FCM using https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send URL, the following error is returned from FCM.

```
{
  "succeeded":false,
  "responseMessage":"Exception occurred; Hostname fcm.googleapis.com not verified:\n    certificate: sha256/AVd9CvtM+BHfQgygNjExC4aOvHSEGRyX7Vvuus9jd9k=\n    DN: CN=*.google.com\n    subjectAltNames: [*.google.com, ...
```

It had been working well and this error started to occur suddenly a few days ago.
In addition, the same FCM request is working well when using Postman.
Is there anybody to help advise this erroneous situation?